# how to search for text and copy rows above the searched text in notedpad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a pattern of lines as below;

```
Click to collapse/expand details
Conference_AddRemovedEventAgain_Verify_SABA-11123:
com.saba.guitest.solvents.PopUp (1)
CentraEventPopUp.waitForPopUpClose     Click to collapse/expand details
Conference_Contribute_Resource: com.saba.guitest.solvents.PopUp (1)
ResourcePopUp.clickAllUsersDelImg      Click to collapse/expand details
Conference_CreateDuplicateEvents_DiffTracks_Verify:
com.saba.guitest.solvents.PopUp (1)
**CentraEventPopUp.waitForPopUpClose**
```

I want to search for a text, say "CentraEventPopUp.waitForPopUpClose", and copy the line just above it. I want to repeat this throughout the whole document.

any idea how will it be possible?

Comment: What have you tried, do you have any code, what language are you using? We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit `CTRL` and `F`, you get the ability to search any document in N++ and other applications such as your internet explorer. Then, scroll to the top of the document, select the top line and hold shift then go to the line above your queried line and it will highlight the whole selection.

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro. Start at the top of the document, with word-wrap off.

1. Start the recorder
2. Open the find dialog and search down for `CentraEventPopUp.waitForPopUpClose`, close the dialog.
3. UP, HOME, and then Shift+END
4. Copy
5. Stop recording